# Show that the set $\left\{\mathbb R\setminus\{p\}: p\in\mathbb R\right\}$ is a subbasis of ${\mathbb R}$ and then find that topology

Tags: general-topology

I had a problem with applying the axioms.
Could anyone navigate me please?

Comment: Do you mean the collection of sets of form $\mathbb R\setminus\{p\}$, for every $p\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes.I don't know why it didn't appear.

Comment: Could you describe the problems you had, in some detail, please? Which axioms are you familiar with, what did you try to verify, which steps do you find challenging? (Have you heard of the cofinite topology?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, any collection of subsets of a set $X$ can be a subbase for a topology on $X$ in *my* book, but some texts, most notably Munkres (it's a recurring theme on this site) demand (as the only condition) that the union of its elements equals $X$. And that is easy enough to verify: $\Bbb R = (\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}) \cup (\Bbb R \setminus \{1\})$, e.g.

The topology it generates has a base consisting of all finite intersections of subbase elements, and those are of the form $\Bbb R \setminus F$, where $F \subset \Bbb R$ is **finite**.

So the topology consists of all unions of base elements, which is the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification

Comment: yes but i have a problem that the basis's elements are ${R}\F$ when F is finite.And the topology induced from it is the union of the basis's elements. Then how can i conclude that it is the cofinite topology (cuz it does not have the same "shape")?

Comment: @Maths1999_ A union of cofinite sets is still cofinite, so the base *is* the topology already, we only add $\emptyset$ as the empty union.

Comment: Yes, but i mean that R\F is not a finite set then bow the union would be finite (the cofinite topology consists of sets that their complement are finite and the empty set)?

Comment: @Maths1999_ if only one set in a union is cofinite, so is the union.